# Call a variable from a data.frame stored in a list

Tags: r

I have created a function to transform data. It returns me a list of two `dataframe`:

```
df1$v1 df1$v2 // df2$v1 df2$v2

dflist <- c(df1, df2)
```

I need to **subset variables** inside of each `dataframe` separately in a shiny app as reactive value.

I tried to subset them with

```
dflist[[1]]["v1"]
```

But it's not subset as the 1st variable of the 1st `dataframe` of the list but as a data.frame

```
class(dflist[[1]]["v1"])
```

returns me `dataframe`, and I want the class of my variable instead.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note on terminology: you “call” functions, not variables. You access them, or subset based on them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to do `[[`

```
dflist[[1]][["v1"]]
```

or use a `,`

```
dflist[[1]][,"v1"]
```

because

```
dflist[[1]]["v1"]
```

is still a `data.frame` of single column

Comment: You lit up my lantern! Thanks